# Django dynamic query in model manager

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im having a problem where i use the same code over and over again (to save an item, than an item transaction for that item).

So i thought maybe i need a Model Manager which will help me with this, and im not very experienced in django, so i would like to know how do you handle this kind of problems.

My idea was to create a InventoryManager like:

```
class InventoryManager(models.Manager):
    def create_item(self, **kwargs):
        #

    def create_item_trans(self, item, **kwargs):
        pass

    def create_item_with_trans(self, **kwargs):
        #  create item
        #  create item_trans
        #  return item with item_trans
```

But in the create_item_with_trans, i dont have a way to send the
**kwargs, cause **create_item** acceps different kwargs, and **create_item_transaction** accepts different **kwargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine something like this:

```
def create_item(self, **kwargs):
    # kwargs = {'item_attr1': '', 'item_attr2': ''}

def create_item_trans(self, item, **kwargs):
    # kwargs = {'item_pk': 1, 'trans_attr1': '', 'trans_attr2': ''}

def create_item_with_trans(self, **kwargs):
    # kwargs = {'item_attr1': '', 'item_attr2': '', 'transaction': {'trans_attr1': '', 'trans_attr2': ''}}

    trans_attrs = kwargs.pop('transaction')
    item = self.create_item(**kwargs)
    trans = self.create_trans(item_pk=item.pk, **trans_attrs)
    #  return item with item_trans
```

Comment: I was also thinking about this like sending an dict like:

`{'item' { ... }, 'item_trans': { ...} }`
But i wasn't sure if this is the correct way, thanks a lot

Comment: Do you think i should write this on the Models Manager or i should create a separate file, where ill hold all my helper functions ?

Comment: I usually create a `managers.py` inside my app and put the `models.Manager` subclasses there. No need for a helpers file.